# Is supergemming possible in Gemcraft Labyrinth?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

In Gemcraft 1 and Gemcraft 0 you could combine high level gem with low level gem (difference must be at least 2 grades). It increased the damage, fire rate, range and specials.

I tried to do this in Gemcraft Labyrinth but the damage, fire rate and range got lower. Also when i combined low pure gem into high dual gem, the special from low gem stayed the same and the other has lowered.

So is increasing the gem grade by upgrading, or combining same grades the only way to strengthen a gem (not counting amplifiers of course)?

Answer (score 2):

For Gemcraft Labrynth, supergemming is still possible. From the wiki:

> Since GCL red gems have the ability to incease their attack damage dramatically by killing enemys. So they are the best for supergemming.
>
> How to do exactly:
>
> First get a strong red gem and place it in a tower. There should be no
>   other things that can kill enemys but this one red gem so it gets all
>   the kills. This will lead to enormous damage values. Support the red
>   supergem with (up to 8) amplifiers that contain further red gems to
>   incease the impact of its ability. To anger the incoming waves is also
>   important because it will cause more enemies what will lead to more
>   kills for the gem to incease its damage value. The supergem can also
>   be mixed with other colors if you want. Best combination is
>   red-lime-yellow because it hits multiple enemys with the multiple
>   amount of its huge damage value. The normal way of supergemming can
>   still be used to incease the damage and speed further.